# CoffeeScript: Spurious comma in comprehension joined by empty separator

Tags: coffeescript, list-comprehension

I wanted a convenience function to catenate jQuery parent > child selector strings. I can't get the following to work in CS 1.10.0 (also tested in 1.7.1). What am I doing wrong?

```
pcsel = (parent_sel, child_sels...) ->
    ### Uitlity for forming parent > child selector string ###
    childchain = [" > " + child for child in child_sels]
    parent_sel + childchain.join('')

console.log pcsel("foo", "bar") # OK. yields "foo > bar"
console.log pcsel("foo", "bar", "glop") # BAD. yields "foo > bar, > glop"
# Sanity check
console.log "foo" + [" > bat", " > glop"].join('') # OK. yields "foo > bar > glop"
```

Thanks!

(I've also posted this as an issue in the CS repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop comprehension:

```
expr for e in array
```

evaluates to an array. That means that this:

```
[ expr for e in array ]
```

is actually a single element array whose first (and only) element is the array from the loop. More explicitly:

```
i for i in [1,2,3]
```

is `[1,2,3]` but this:

```
[ i for i in [1,2,3] ]
```

is `[[1,2,3]]`.

Your problem is that `childchain` in `pcsel` ends up with an extra level of nesting and the stringification from the `join` call adds unexpected commas.

The solution is to fix `pcsel`:

```
childchain = (" > " + child for child in child_sels)
# -----------^-------------------------------------^
```

You need the parentheses (not brackets) to get around precedence issues; parentheses (`()`) and brackets (`[]`) serve entirely different functions so you need to use the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the behavior you're seeing is what's to be expected. Here's how your code behaves if you replace the splat with an explicit array:

```
coffee> ["> " + ['bar']]        # => ['> bar']
coffee> ["> " + ['bar', 'baz']] # =>['> bar,baz']
```

You'll also see the same behavior in node:

```
> [">" + ['bar']]         // => ['>bar']
> ["> " + ['bar', 'baz']] // => ['> bar,baz']
```

You could achieve what you're after using multiple calls to `.join`, or by doing something like this:

```
pcsel = (parent_sel, child_sels...) ->    
    child_sels.reduce (memo, sel) ->
        memo + " > #{sel}"
    , parent_sel

console.log pcsel("foo", "bar") # => foo > bar
console.log pcsel("foo", "bar", "glop") # => foo > bar > glop
console.log pcsel("foo", "bar", "glop", "baz") # => foo > bar > glop > baz
```